# Mapping a string into a Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am fairly new to Javascript is there a way in which we can achieve the following result?

```
const bikes = ["honda","kawasaki",suzuki]
```

The main object array can be divided into equal parts based on the number of bikes, like the first few rows with the main object will be "honda", the next few groups of rows "Kawasaki" and if more rows are added to the bikes that divided the main object further into equal parts and update

```
const mainObject =[ 
    { name:"john", age:"23"},
    { name:"Max", age:"26"},
    { name:"Tim", age:"28"},
    { name:"Jim", age:"28"},
    { name:"Jacob", age:"28"},
    { name:"Luke", age:"28"}
]
```

The expected Outcome should be

```
const mainObject =[ 
    { name:"john", age:"23",bike:"honda"},
    { name:"Max", age:"26",bike:"honda"},
    { name:"Tim", age:"28",bike:"kawasaki"},
    { name:"Jim", age:"28",bike:"kawasaki"},
    { name:"Jacob", age:"28",bike:"suzuki"},
    { name:"Luke", age:"28", bike:"suzuki"}
]
```

Comment: Your objects are not valid. Everything in an object must be `key:value`, but you have no keys for the bikes.

Comment: Divide the number of elements in `mainObject` by the length of `bikes`. Then loop through the bikes array and add the current bike to the next N elements of `mainObject`.

Comment: What means *".I need to re"*? Please [edit] your question, add what you tried by providing a [mcve], fix your question code issues beforehand, also (since you have not) take a [tour].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
result = mainObject.map((o, i) => ({
    ...o,
    bike: bikes[Math.floor(i * bikes.length / mainObject.length)]
}))
```